# Change SharePoint group owner with Powershell to a SharePoint group

Tags: 2013, powershell, security, groups

I have this PS script to change the group owner of a SharePoint group to a domain user.  I would like to use this script to change it to an existing SharePoint group.  The current script only allows for domain users....

Any ideas?

```
#Get the SPWeb
$web = Get-SPWeb "URL"

#Get the Group
$group = $web.SiteGroups["Group 1"]
$group = $web.SiteGroups["Group 2"]
#Get the User 
$user = $web.EnsureUser("domain\user")

#Assign that user as the owner
$group.Owner = $user

#Update the Group
$group.Update()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a small change to your PowerShell script.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://webUrl
$groupOwner = $web.SiteGroups["GroupA"] #this group will own "GroupB"
$groupTarget = $web.SiteGroups["GroupB"]
$groupTarget.Owner = $groupOwner
$groupTarget.Update()
```

For all groups in a web:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://webUrl
$groupName = "SharePoint Group Name" #this will be the owner
$groupOwner = $web.SiteGroups[$groupName]

foreach($group in ($web.SiteGroups | ?{$_.Name -ne $groupName}))
{
    $group.Owner = $groupOwner
    $group.Update()
}
```

Comment: OK new problem.  I've used this code successfully but I know want to change the owner of more than one group so I re use the $groupTarget = $web.SiteGroups["GroupB"] so it reads $groupTarget = $web.SiteGroups["GroupC"] etc but it doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Groups can only be owned by a single object (User or Group).

Comment: So how can I use a script to set the owner for multiple sharepoint groups?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Getting the following error .....Exception setting "Owner": "Cannot convert the "Key User" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPMember"."
At line:4 char:1
+ $groupTarget.Owner = $groupOwner

Comment: Made a small mistake in my answer, missing a closing parenthesis.